# Looking for some nice & easy html 5 3d engine, similar to papervision3d for flash

Tags: javascript, html

I wan't to do some experimens with html5 and 3d and looking for some nice 3d engine. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to look at [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js) or [CubicVR.js](https://github.com/cjcliffe/CubicVR.js).